# What file type do we need to associate a .wav or .mp3 file in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mp3

So, I am trying to do an ASR by sending a .mp3 file to the API provided. I am running normally in a Python script and it is working quite fine and giving me the perfect response. But now I am trying to do the same in Android Studio and using Java for that. I have created a `raw` directory in the `res` directory of my project. So this is how the .mp3 file is saved - `res/raw/yes.mp3` - `yes.mp3` is the name of the file. But then, after I write the code, I get this output:

> {"reason":"'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filename'", "status": "failure"}

But I have set the correct file path and everything. So, I think there might be some error in how I am associating the .mp3 file. I have associated it with Text, and Archive, and ignored it, but every time the same error. So, with what do I associate the .mp3 file?

Comment: Could you provide the code that you wrote?

Comment: "But I have set the correct file path and everything" -- there is no "file path" to a app's resource on a phone. You might consider editing your question to include a [mcve].